# Retrieving people who +1 an URL

Tags: ruby, google-plus, google-plus-one, ripple

I've burning out the past 2 days trying to come with a recipe to get all the People who have +1 an URL, I'm trying to calculate the potential reach of a publication in Google+.

I did get the public shares of a URL using Ripple, amount and users, but is not the same.

I writing my app in ruby, but at this moment, I can't care less about the language.

To get clear view of my problem, please read my comment below.

Comment: Maybe a little code would help. Otherwise I fear your post will be ravaged by down votes and flames will ignite, until this chaos is quelled by your post being locked.

Comment: You didn't tell us anything useful that we can use to help you. We have to know what you're requesting and what you're receiving and why those aren't getting what you need.

Comment: I have no code for this, just getting the count or such. I'll try to explain more.
Let's say you are in a news site, you will always see these social buttons, **Share** in Twitter, **Like/Share** in Facebook, **+1** in Google Plus, **Share** in Linkedin to name a few. In order to get the social reach of this news post, I need to get the individual reach of every person who engaged with the content, getting who +1 is part of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API method to get a list of who as +1'd a URL. If you would like to see such a feature please [open a new issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list).

Comment: Thanks **abraham**, I will.